# i keep on getting mismatch error in excel 2007 in VB

Tags: excel, excel-2007, runtime-error, type-mismatch, vba

Hope all is well with you.

I want to ask help for my excel vb. I am not sure what else do i need to edit in my codes since the calculation works but the run time error mismatch type always pop up.

```
    Private Sub txtQty_Change()
 VAT.Value = txtQty.Value * 0.12
End Sub
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's most likely a wrong cell type in Excel or wrong string type in VBA.

Comment: i named my textbox as VAT. What i am planning to do is to show in VAT the product of the value i entered in txtqty multiplied by 0.12. thanks

Comment: what value do you enter in `txtQty`?

Comment: once i entered 200 in txtqty, i am getting 24 in VAT which is correct. But once I submit the form to populate the values on the spreadsheet, the values are there but the run time error 13 and type mismatch. the error is in ' vat.value = txtqty.value * 0.12 '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

This will ensure that if the `txtQty_Change` is automatically called again then it won't create any problem.

```
Private Sub txtQty_Change()
    if Len(Trim(txtQty.Value)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    VAT.Value = txtQty.Value * 0.12
End Sub
```